# Java JsonMappingException when accessing SQL resultset

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
PreparedStatement getUser = null;
Connection con = null;
try {
    dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mfp");
    ...

    con = dataSource.getConnection();
    getUser = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");

    getUser.setString(1, username);

    ResultSet data = getUser.executeQuery();

    if (data.first()) {
        if (data.getString("username").equals(username) && data.getString("password").equals(password)) {
```

In the last line, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.lang.Object and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.sample.UserLogin["dataSource"]->org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource["connectionPool"]->org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool["_pool"]->java.util.LinkedList[0]->org.apache.commons.pool.impl.ObjectTimestampPair["value"]->org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection["_conn"]->com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection["charsetConverterMap"]->java.util.HashMap["UTF-8"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
```

When I am debugging the line, the `watch` section shows `true` for both comparisons:

`data.getString("username").equals(username)`--> ``` true`` ```
data.getString("password").equals(password)`-->`true`

Comment: Could you share the values inside the `data`, or what you can do is Use the `JSONParser` to parse the `data` and then proceed with the parsed json data.

Comment: _res: JDBC42ResultSet  (id=33310); 
_stmt: DelegatingPreparedStatement  (id=33300), 
config: null; 
createdBy: null; 
createdTime: 0; 
lastUsed: 0; 
parent: null; 
trace: ArrayList<E>  (id=33312);

Comment: How can I parse `data` with `JSONParser`. `data`is `org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet`

Comment: Well, Consider this resource: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception